# avoid truncated text in cell

Tags: google-fusion-tables

My fusion table contains columns with text that are rendered illegible due to the text size limit:

```
Bartonella effector protein (Bep), substrate of Vi…
```

Resizing the column has no effect on the truncation. Is there a way to increase the size of the displayed text?

Comment: Have you tried the "new look"? Just click the "Switch to new look" link in the upper right corner of the web ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new look also has the 50 character limit in the row layout, but if you use the card layout then you can see one record at a time with no truncation.

Rod

Comment: thanks Rod. It would be great to have the character limit in the row layout removed: what's the point of being able to resize a column if it does not allow you to read the actual cell content?